# How do I not use an interface when mocking?

Tags: go, testify

I am trying to avoid using an interface because my use cases do not require it (similarly mentioned in https://www.ardanlabs.com/blog/2016/10/avoid-interface-pollution.html). However, to create a mock (using `testify`), wouldn't I need an interface to mock? I could create one, but it seems tedious. All the places my code is used would require writing interfaces for their mocking, not for their actual usage. Is there a workaround?

Comment: "my use cases do not require it" -- not true. Testing requires it. Testing is a use case.

Comment: you can try use `pure` functional style  I think it is not convenient way on lack of generics

Comment: Just do not use testify and go for normal testing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the only possible use of an interface is for testing, I agree, that's probably a bad interface, and you should avoid that.

The best way is to refactor your system to rely on a small, *useful* interfaces rather than one-off "mocks" of over-complicated structs. A very good example of this is the `net.Listener` interface. A system built on top of `net.Listener` is easy to mock, yes, but that's not why you implement `net.Listener`. You use the interface because it lets you swap in *many* possible implementations, one of which happens to be for testing.

Another powerful approach is chain together functions rather than hard-coding functionality as methods. `http.HandlerFunc` is a great example of this that also demonstrates great interface design. See the many "click-together" functions that return a `http.Handler`, rather than one, massive "Handler" struct that you'd then have to mock for testing. This is Go at its best IMO.

Remembering that functions are first-class in Go, you can get a lot of flexibility by passing and returning functions rather than tying them to interfaces. When you do that, you also can bundle those together as a struct. This can give a lot of power that also happens to be useful for testing. For example see, `tls.Config` which allows you to include your own `GetCertificate` function (among others). But the `tls.Config` struct also has sensible defaults so you don't have to configure every piece every time. By passing a specialized version of `tls.Config`, you can test TLS functionality without "mocking" anything.

The consistent theme here is to make your system flexible about its implementations, and as a nice side-effect, that makes testing easier. In my experience, this is a much better way to think about the problem than mocking.

Comment: Thanks! Still learning more here. Interesting that one could use the functions as "adapters". Also, interesting point with `tls.Config`. It seems one could generate the "mock" essentially for clients, so they do not need to mock anything.

Answer (score 2):

You need an interface to mock because the mock *is* your second implementation, so if you're using mocks in unit tests, then your use case *does* require it. The interface serves as a placeholder to be filled with some implementation of that functionality. You're planning to have at least two such implementations: one mock, one production. In order to be able to use them interchangeably for testing, you *must* use an interface.

Comment: True. That makes sense.

Answer (score -3):

To reduce the amount of repetition with mocking larger interfaces, it appears one could use something like `vectra/mockery` to generate the mocks. Not a solution to removing the need for an interface, however, but I think Rob mentions some good ideas for that below.